# Dynamic Sprite creating in SWIFT

Tags: swift, text, dynamic, sprite

I am trying to create a tile for a game and have a small graphic and want to center a letter in the middle of it.

Because I need more than 100 different tiles (different letters on top), I like to create them dynamically. Loading the background tile, writing a letter on top of it, save it as a sprite and then use it like the normal way:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: MySpriteName)
```

Then I can add it to a layer etc.
Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a SpriteNode with the background image you want.

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg.png")
```

Now make a SKLabel for the Letter that will go on top.

```
 let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "OpenSans-Bold")
  label.name = "letterLabel"
  label.fontSize = 12
  label.fontColor = UIColor(red: 0.47, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
  label.text = "A"
```

Add the label to the Sprite as a child.

```
sprite.addChild(label)
```

add the sprite to the SKScene.

```
self.addChild(sprite)
```

You will need to change the size, color, and position to make it look how you want.